# How do I save a csv string to a file?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a function that generates a csv string, `getSummaryCsvString()`. I want to save it to a file so that it can then be used with a send intent so the user can email the file, save it to Google Drive, etc. But when I try to save a file, I get this error:

```
Writing csv summary failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: summary.csv: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

The relevant code:

```
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) = when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.summaryExportBtn -> {
            val filename = "summary.csv"
            val summaryFile = File.createTempFile("summary", "csv")
            val fileWriter: FileWriter?

            try {
                fileWriter = FileWriter(filename)
                fileWriter.append(getSummaryCsvString())
                Log.d(FDSLogTag, "Writing csv summary succeeded")
                val sendIntent = Intent()
                sendIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, summaryFile)
                sendIntent.type = "text/csv"
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "SHARE"))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(FDSLogTag, "Writing csv summary failed: $e")
                val toast = Toast.makeText(this.applicationContext, "Writing csv summary failed: $e", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                toast.show()
            }

            true
        }

        else -> {
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

How do I successfully save the csv string to a file and share it?

Comment: Replace your `createTempFile()` stuff with writing the file to a specific known directory, such as `getCacheDir()` on `Context`. Then, use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()` to get a `Uri` to use with `EXTRA_STREAM`. See https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing and https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.

Comment: @CommonsWare I get the same error message when I use the cache dir: `val summaryFile = File(cacheDir, "summary.csv")`

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide the complete stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a file provider in your AndroidManifest.xml file in the `<application>` section:

```xml
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Next, create the provider paths file provider_paths.xml in app > res > xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="mypath" path="mypath/" />
</paths>
```

Finally, write the code to create the file. It's important to check if the directory exists; if it doesn't, it needs to be created.

```kotlin
try {
    val filename = "myfilename.csv"
    val myPath = File(filesDir, "mypath") // mypath must match your provider xml path attribute
    if (!myPath.exists()) {
        myPath.mkdir()
    }
    val myFile = File(myPath, filename)

    FileOutputStream(myFile).use { stream ->
        stream.write(myCsvString.toByteArray())
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.d("logtag", "Writing csv failed: $e")
    val toast = Toast.makeText(this.applicationContext, "Writing csv failed: $e", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    toast.show()
}
```